# My screen isn't fully visible on my monitor

Tags: 18.04

I've recently installed Ubuntu on a older computer and a old monitor (which the system calls a [BenQ 241w](https://www.benq.com/en-us/support/downloads-faq/products/monitor/fp241w/manual.html)) and despite all my efforts the monitor refuses to show the whole screen (I messed around in both display settings and the monitor settings)

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
Linux dna 5.3.0-45-generic #37~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 15:58:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Comment: Please open a terminal & run `lsb_release -a && uname -a && lshw -c video | grep configuration`. Highlight & copy the resulting text then come back here, click [edit], & paste the text into your question. Also. which version of Linux have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] & add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about the PC should go in the Question with [edit]..

Comment: What is the output of `xrandr`?

Answer (score 1):

Try Auto Adjustment from the On Screen Display as shown starting on [page 26 of your manual](https://benqesupport.blob.core.windows.net/esupport/LCD%20Monitor/UserManual/LCD%20Monitor_um_User%20Manual_20070529_161853_fp241W-en.pdf).

The native res of the Benq 241w is 1920x1200 which is not common, so having to adjust it is not unexpected.

Comment: Or adjust System > Display mode in monitor settings. (p. 42)